# how to terminate a java code in linux using

Tags: java, linux

I'm running a java Code using the command java -jar Code.jar...
I want now to terminate the program, how can I end the program using command line Linux?

Comment: `Kill <pid>` using PID of your program.

Comment: Of course, this is not an advanced question, but the @downvoters should provide some explanation...

Comment: the name of the code is Code.jar
so I write Kill Code.jar??

Comment: @Rohan you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: To find the process running your jar, use `ps aux | grep java` or `ps aux | grep Code.jar`, it will give your the process ID, then you use `kill <process_number>`.

Comment: the java code is get different process ID each second so how to terminate it??

Comment: maybe "killall java", if you don't have anything else important in java running at that time.

Answer (score 3):

Usually pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will terminate the application.

You could also find the process ID for the process (use [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) to see a list of running processes) and then kill the process using the [`kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command.

Comment: I can't use Ctrl-C because I run the program in different computer and now I want to terminate it

Comment: @user1475288: You run the program in a different computer? What do you mean?

Comment: I run the program on my lab server on my lab computer and now I'm home so I need to terminate the Code or else :(

Comment: @user1475288: Do you have shell access to the lab computer?

Comment: @user1475288 do you have a remote access ??

Comment: yes I have access to the server

Comment: @user1475288 you should edit your question and explain the whole situation. Community people don't have a crystal ball to guess what exact problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options some of which have been covered.
Since you aren't at the machine in question you can't use ctrl+c obviously.

You could manually identify the pid with ps (ps -ef|grep ) and then kill it with the aformentioned kill

but I prefer pkill if it is available on the system. The pkill command will search the process tree for what you specify and kill that. It is similall to the killall command however pkill is grepping the processes extended attributes where killall only works on the process names. In this case your process is java but you probably don't want to kill all instances of java only the specific one so with pkill you can use the name of the jar file.

pkill Code.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Ctrl-C` or just close the **terminal** ..